# Sending xml post request to geoserver

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wfs, geoext, http-post

This may be simple question but I can't get started. This tutorial from [pen state university](https://courseware.e-education.psu.edu/courses/geog585/content/lesson03/6.html) has xml request

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS"  version="1.0.0"
  outputFormat="GML2"  – we would like gml2 as the return format
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
  http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:bc_roads">  we want to query 
                bc_roads features
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:FeatureId fid="bc_roads.1"/> only return features 
                                        with an ID of bc_roads.1
    </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

My question here is how do I send this request to geoserver using geoext or javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a post request in OpenLayers like this:

```
var postData = ""; //insert your data to post here

var request = new OpenLayers.Request.POST({
    url: "http://host/path",
    data: postData,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=utf-8"
    },
    callback: function (response) {
        //read the response from GeoServer
        var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({ extractAttributes: true });
        var features = gmlReader.read(response.responseText);
        // do what you want with the features returned...
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("Something went wrong in the request");
    }
});
```

You can see more examples of how to request data in OpenLayers here:

[Requesting Remote Data](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html)

Comment: great I will try this but I wanted to use geoext

Comment: Since *GeoExt* is an extension to combine *ExtJS* and *OpenLayers*, you might as well use OpenLayers to perform the request. You could use the `XMLHttpRequest` like **BicycleDude** suggest, but you could also use ExtJS to do the same. You have several API's at your hand - each capable of requesting :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to make the following assumptions:

- url = **http://insert.your.url.com/path** (which will be wrong)
- your not using any library, i.e. no jQuery, no AJAX
- you're interested in the built in XMLHttpRequest() object
- you would like to handle asynchronous requests (instead of synchronous)
- you can replace the error / success handler with something else
- you wan't to see a minimal but complete working HTML

Here's the starter code in HTML / JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WMS Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
  function doit()
  {
    var url = 'http://insert.your.url.com/path';
    var method = 'POST';
    var postData =
      '<wfs:GetFeature\n'
      + '  service="WFS"\n'
      + '  version="1.0.0"\n'
      + '  outputFormat="GML2"\n'
      + '  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"\n'
      + '  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\n'
      + '  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"\n'
      + '  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n'
      + '  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs\n'
      + '  http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">\n'
      + '  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:bc_roads">\n'
      + '    <ogc:Filter>\n'
      + '      <ogc:FeatureId fid="bc_roads.1"/>\n'
      + '    </ogc:Filter>\n'
      + '    </wfs:Query>\n'
      + '</wfs:GetFeature>\n';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'XMLHTTP/1.0');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState != 4) return;
      if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
        alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
        return;
      }
      alert(req.responseText);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="doit" onclick="doit()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 ...and probably using jQuery would not be a bad idea!

Comment: Great suggestion, but the OP wanted to use *GeoExt* ;)