# How to add Checkboxes in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, layers

I have a POI table with some data of categories like Airport,ATM,Bank etc. I want to show these categories as checkbox so that if I click in the ATM Checkbox, only the ATM Points will be display. Is there any option in Geoserver?

Regards,
Sreesha

Answer (score 4):

Achieving this will involve both the client library you are using as well as GeoServer. On the GeoServer part, you can retrieve the names of the ATMs using `gs:Unique` WPS process. To use the WPS process, you must have installed the WPS plugin. Refer to [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/index.html) for details on GeoServer WPS plugin.

You can create the `gs:Unique` query to use in your request using the WPS Query Builder. You can then copy the process XML to your client, issue a POST request from your client to GeoServer's WPS URL, something like localhost:8080/geoserver/wps. You can specify that you want your response in XML or JSON format in your POST request. With the ATM names now on the client side, you can choose to represent them to end users with checkboxes. Refer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20722/sending-xml-post-request-to-geoserver) to see how to use `POST` with OpenLayers, and how to access the response.

Based on a user's selection, you can use CQL filters to selectively display a `Point` (ATM). Refer to [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) for details on CQL.

UPDATE: I'm assuming you already have your data in PostGIS, and have already created a feature type (layer) based on the PostGIS table.