# Adding features to vector layer from WFS query using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I am trying to add the resulting WFS features (xml format) to my selected items vector layer but can't get it to work.

I am querying my WFS layer with the following:

```
    showFeatureLink.on('click', function() {
        OpenLayers.Request.GET({
            url: 'http://1.2.3.4:8080/geoserver/wfs',
            params: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typeName: 'Mylines:WebLayer1'
            },
            proxy: "../gis/geoserver.seam?url=",
            success: function(request) {
                var features = new OpenLayers.Format.WFS().read(response.responseText);
                selected_items.addFeatures(features);
                map.zoomToExtent(selected_items.getDataExtent());
            },
    });
```

The XML returned contains all the relevant information so there's no problem there.

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="1000"...... />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of it using [Sending xml post request to geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20722/sending-xml-post-request-to-geoserver)

The answer is to use a GML object and convert this to a list of features using the following code in the success block:

```
success: function(response) {
    var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({ extractAttributes: true });
    var features = gmlReader.read(response.responseText);
    selected_items.addFeatures(features);
    map.zoomToExtent(selected_items.getDataExtent());
}
```