# Problem with cql_filter condition in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

In openlayers-3 I am using the below code to update my WMS layers with
`cql_filter` condition based on user selection:

```
filterstring = "intersects(geom," + geomInwkt + ")";

wmsLayer.getSource().updateParams({'cql_filter': filterstring});
```

This code is working fine as long as my filterstring value is small but whenever I am passing a long string to `cql_filter`, I am not getting a response from Geoserver.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Probably passing the length limit of http GET with a big wkt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably reach the length limit of http GET with a big WKT string.
Consider the use of POST Request.

More info na doc do geoserver:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

And here:
[Sending xml post request to geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20722)

WMS example from Anita's blog:
https://anitagraser.com/2010/06/09/getmap-from-geoserver-using-http-post

Comment: but I am using wms service and every time I need to refresh the layer with updated filterstring based on selection. Could you provide me any example related to WMS.

Comment: @pkpanda updated. Last link is about your problem....